# reusing tree traversal methods vs creating a new traversal method

Tags: algorithm, tree, computer-science, traversal

I'm using the problem below as an example.

I'm trying to solve this problem http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-maximum-path-sum-in-a-binary-tree/ and I understand the solution provided which recursively traverses that tree. But I am wondering if it makes more sense to solve it as a client utilizing standard tree APIs which may include an iterable list of nodes in inorder/ pre/post order of the nodes.

I am not a professional software developer and don't use data structures at work. So my questions to you are

1) Does it make more sense to solve this type of problem as a client utilizing tree traversal methods of a DS in a library. (Assumption: such traversal methods exist).

2) In the context of an interview for software dev (sorry if this breaks the rules of this community), will the interviewers expect that I solve this as a method of a tree DS? i.e., I have access to the root and then I can traverse the tree like in the solution. or will they prefer that I solve it as a client.

3) What about 2) as a professional software dev in day to day work.

I apologize if the question in confusing or not well stated.

Comment: those libraries most likely will do a recursive tree traversal to give you the nodes so it's the same in the end - also it's not really the point of solving a problem by using anothers solution ;) (at least not for those puzzles) ^^ - and if you are ask such a question then yes you are expected to come up with a solution (or at least show that you can demonstrate your understanding of the problem ... which is different from being able to use a library)

Comment: btw: 99.x% of devs will never see such problems in their day to day work ... all we do is BLOBAs (boring line of business applications) :(

Answer (score 0):

In interview questions they would want you to come up with the solution yourself, rather than just say "I would use this standard library", even if that's what you would do if you were actually solving the proglem.